# SQL: Lookup / Insert value from another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to lookup up a value from one table and insert it into a second table.

My two tables are called [FEBW14_FFA68878_Calls] and [CLIMapping] and I would like to lookup the [Customer ID] value based on a lookup of the [CustomerCLI] / [CLI]

My code kind of works, but inserts additional rows rather than updating the [Customer Lookup] field for the existing rows

Here is the code I am using, can anyone help me out with the correct syntax.

```
INSERT INTO [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[febW14_FFA68878_Calls] ([Customer Lookup])
SELECT [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[customer id]
FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping]
JOIN [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[FEBW14_FFA68878_Calls] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[FEBW14_FFA68878_Calls].[CustomerCLI] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[CLI];
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you're using 2008 or greater, look into using `MERGE` as it performs an `UPSERT`.

Comment: You mention you are trying to insert rows (INSERT Statement) but then say it is not updating existing rows (UPDATE statement), are you trying to do both?

Comment: I guess it is an UPDATE - I would like to add the [Customer ID] value, based on the lookup from the CLIMapping table

Answer (score 0):

In case it will help anyone else, I needed an UPDATE statement.

Here is the code I used to lookup a value from another table.

```
UPDATE [febW14_FFA68878_Calls] 
SET    [febW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Customer Lookup] = CLIMapping.[customer id]
FROM   [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping]
INNER JOIN [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[FEBW14_FFA68878_Calls] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[FEBW14_FFA68878_Calls].[CustomerCLI] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[CLI]
```